# postgres select some or all records - using null in query

Tags: postgresql

I want something in postgres, just as we write filter queries in sql - where we need some matching or all records to be returned.

```
WITH myvars (t_state, t_crashtype, t_speedzone)as (
values('ABC', 'Intersection', 50))
SELECT 
                            dr_sex, 
                            COUNT(*) as all_crashes, 
                            COUNT(t1.id) filter (WHERE severity_id >= 3) as fsi_crashes,
                            COUNT(t1.id) filter (WHERE severity_id = 3) as si_crashes,
                            COUNT(t1.id) filter (WHERE severity_id = 4) as fatal_crashes
            FROM 
                            t1
            JOIN 
                            t2 ON t1.id = t2.crash_id
            LEFT JOIN 
                            ( 
                                            SELECT id, lga_name19 FROM geom
                            ) t3 ON t2.lga_id = t3.id
                            ,myvars
            WHERE 
                            (jurisdiction = t_state OR t_state = null)
                            AND (crash_type_std = t_crashtype OR t_crashtype = null)
                            AND (speed_zone = t_speedzone OR t_speedzone = null)
                            
                            AND dr_sex = ANY( '{Male, Female}'::text[] ) 
            GROUP BY dr_sex
```

speed_zone column is nullable integer, as soon as I set t_speedzone as null

> operator does not exist: integer = text

also, if I set t_state as null nothing is returned in resultset

Comment: Use is null instead of = null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used cast and also replaced = null with is null

```
WITH myvars (t_state, t_crashtype, t_speedzone)as (
values(null, 'Intersection', null))
SELECT 
                            dr_sex, 
                            COUNT(*) as all_crashes, 
                            COUNT(t1.id) filter (WHERE severity_id >= 3) as fsi_crashes,
                            COUNT(t1.id) filter (WHERE severity_id = 3) as si_crashes,
                            COUNT(t1.id) filter (WHERE severity_id = 4) as fatal_crashes
            FROM 
                            t1
            JOIN 
                            t2 ON t1.id = t2.crash_id
            LEFT JOIN 
                            ( 
                                            SELECT id, lga_name19 FROM geom
                            ) t3 ON t2.lga_id = t3.id
                            ,myvars
            WHERE 
            
                            (jurisdiction = t_state OR t_state is null)
                            AND (crash_type_std = t_crashtype OR t_crashtype is null)
                            AND (speed_zone = cast(t_speedzone as integer) OR  t_speedzone is null)
                            
                            AND dr_sex = ANY( '{Male, Female}'::text[] )
            GROUP BY dr_sex
```

Comment: Another option is to use `null::integer` in your VALUES clause